# Creating/Duplicating a Certificate Template with Powershell

Tags: powershell, certificate, powershell-2.0

I want to create a template using powershell but I cannot seem to figure out how to set a `Minimum Supported CA` for the template.  I was never able to figure out how to duplicate a template, just create a new one.

My code is as follows

```
$temp = ([ADSI]"LDAP://RootDSE".ConfigurationNamingContext
$ADSI = [ADSI]"LDAP://CN=Certificate Templates,CN=Public Key Services, CN=Services,$config"

$temp = $ADSI.Create("pKICertificateTemplate","CN=Web Server 2008-2")
$temp.put("distinguishedName","CN=Web Server 2008-2,CM=Certificate Template,CN=Public Key Services,CN=Services.$Config)

$temp.SetInfo()
```

This works to create an actual template, but I want the template to be created using `Windows Server 2008 Enterprise` as the `Minimum Supported CAs`

Answer (score 1):

In ADCS, a version 1 cert is Win200, version 2 is 2003, and version 3 is 2008.

I don't have a lab to verify in, but I think you need to set the template schema to 3:

```
$temp.put("msPKI-Template-Schema-Version","3")
$temp.put("msPKI-Template-Minor-Revision","0")  # Not sure if you actually need this.
```

["Source..kinda"](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverpowershell/thread/347acc93-8352-4535-ab1a-23ebd49eea22/)

Comment: This appears to work, but the template never actually shows up.  If I run it consecutively I receive the error message that `the object already exists` this tells me it is actually working...but the template is nowhere to be found.

Comment: As said, I can't help any further. Read the source I included. Used that and noticed the schema-version attribute.  Btw, your sample has an error where you set the DN for the new object. It should be `...CN=Certificate Template,....` not `...CM=Certificate Template,....` :-)

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround (not for every scenario), you can duplicate/set a certificate template manually once (on your CA) and export that template using [`ldifde`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/cc731033(v=ws.11)) (on your DC). E. g., you duplicated the `Webserver` template and called it `Webserver Custom`:

```
ldifde -m -d 'CN=WebserverCustom,CN=Certificate Templates,CN=Public Key Services,CN=Services,CN=Configuration,DC=contoso,DC=com' -f .\webservercustom.ldf
```

Later, in some kind of automation, you can import that template by issuing:

```
ldifde -i -f .\webservercustom.ldf
```